# How this 9 LED Knight Rider Circuit Works Properly?

Tags: led

I have recently started working on **[9 LED Knight Rider Circuit](http://www.electronicshub.org/led-running-lights-circuit/)** on a breadboard. All the connections have been done according to the circuit diagram given in this article. But I am having a problem with it - The light is running only one way instead of coming back and forth. Can anybody identify the problem and suggest me the modifications to be done to this circuit arrangement?

Comment: Sorry, but that's a truly **atrocious** schematic. I think it was badly copied from somewhere else.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, which is probably the original. It's available on [this website](http://webspace.webring.com/people/gl/lemagicien/elecpage/bounlite/bounlight.html). The schematic you linked has **many** problems, such as outputs shorted to ground or to other outputs, inputs connected to inputs only (transistor drive) etc.

[image]

Connect each LED with a series resistor from each output \$Q_I\$ to ground.

Comment: Well spotted, I was just looking at the original wondering where anyone was going to start.

Comment: No need for resistors, there is at least 100 Ohms built in the high side driver.

Comment: Which goes to 1000 Ohms with only 5V on this old stuff.

Comment: At 12V you should use resistors. At 5V, with CD4017 (not 74HC4017), no need for series LED resistors. ;-)

Comment: I read the specs and 74HC4017 is 6V max with ESR=365 ohms typ. Based on Voh, Ioh, CD4017 on 15V has an ESR of 220 ohms and 1000 @5V and only one output is active, so Pd is low.

Comment: @Dorito There is no maximum output source current spec, only minimum and typical. It will probably survive for some time regardless, but not good engineering, IMHO.